# Is “swipe for action” on list of items a common pattern on android applications?

Tags: android

What I mean by "swipe for action" is described in the following [site](https://unitid.nl/androidpatterns/uap_pattern/swipe-for-action) (the first image).

I am developping 2 versions of my app, one for android and one for iOS. On iOS device the swipe for action is a common way to perform actions on a list of items. However for android I used to think, that the pattern is a long click on the element and then it displays a menu that shows actions available on that element. Is it still the case, or "swipe for action" is being used as common pattern on android too? The answer to this question might be subjective, I would appreciate references that gives common user experience pattern on android.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE!  Although I am pretty sure I understand what you're describing, I don't see a link to "the following site".  Can you edit that in as well as the specific image if that adds clarity?

Comment: @thunderblaster : thanx for your comment, sorry for link, I firsted posted it on stackoverflow, and I was adviced to post here, and while copy/pasting my post I forgot to add the link. I won't add the image, because it belongs to the owner of the website, I don't know if there are copyright on it or stuffs like that.

Comment: Not an answer because I have no evidence to cite offhand, but I as a user tend to associate swiping list items with removing them (be it deleting emails, dismissing notifications, etc.)

Comment: Also not a full answer but Microsoft Outlook on Android users this pattern: push messages to the left for archiving and to the right for adding to action items. (It should also be noted that I struggled to find any other apps that use this pattern - There may be more but I didn't find them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely would say that it is not common. At least I have yet to find it in Googles Material Design reference. Gmail utilises it to some extent, though, with letting you delete things while swiping. All in all, I'd say it is more of an iOS thing though, especially with the implementation of more that one option being revealed.

Edit:
Now that I have thought more about it I remember seeing from time to time, though (was it with the twitter app?). All in all I still think it is not the most common thing on Android. Also the animation is different in that the icons are static and are revealed upon swiping whereas in iOS they get pushed in from the side.

Comment: As an Android user of multiple years I can confirm that. @Mouss I think you're better off using the long press as you suggested OR use swripe but offer a **small** onboarding experience (tutorial)